# Do I need a router with Mac and these firewall settings?

Tags: router

I am single home user in one apartment with no other users, living apartment block house with over hundred apartments.
I have cable internet and one modem.

Mac firewall has "block all incoming connections" and "enable stealth mode" enabled.
All sharing services are disabled.

Do I need a router? All ports are disabled with these settings (I assume at least) so is router needed?

Comment: The "modem" is probably already a router too; almost all are these days, but without model details we can't be certain. In short, you must have a router somewhere, otherwise you cannot 'see' the internet. Whether that is done in your modem, in your computer, or in a dedicated third device, there still must be one somewhere between you & the outside world.

Comment: @Tetsujin My modem is Scientific Atlanta 2203. I had no idea router had to be somewhere already. Is there any way to tell what it is in my case?

Comment: Ugh, I just looked up the spec on the device. It's ancient & actually hands off elsewhere for routing, so in fact you really would need a router in front of it. Didn't know that sort of device was still in use these days. My bad. http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21762942-Is-the-Scientific-Atlanta-DPC2203C-a-router-or-modem

Comment: @Tetsujin Any router would do? Even cheapest ones, if all I want is some firewall?

Comment: probably, but I've no idea what's available for the consumer market, they're supplied by the ISP over here

Answer (score 5):

You only need a router if you want to "route" a network connection to more than 1 device.

If you only want to have 1 device connected to your network then you don't need a router. If you add another network-enabled device (TV, printer, another computer, etc), then you **will** need a router to share & control the network traffic.

Comment: I only have one device and have been like this for years, but heard recently router is needed for for firewall purpose due to attempts on every IP address every day? So is it not needed just for security?

Comment: All firewalls do the same thing so if you only have 1 network connected device (your Mac) it doesn't matter if you have it on your Mac or in a router.  You'll want a router with a built-in firewall if you decide to connect other devices (iPhone, iPad, TV, etc.) to that network connection.  Based on the info you provided in your question, the Mac firewall should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, so no need for router in my case? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Fsb is correct that you only need a router if you wish to connect to your network with another device.

But this doesn't mean you necessarily have to add a physical router. Instead, you can connect to your modem with Ethernet cable (if you aren't already) and then use the Sharing options in your System Preferences to share your internet via Wifi. This would allow other devices (such as an iPhone) to connect to a new wifi network setup by your Mac because your Mac has become the *router* for you!

Comment: I have been without router for years, but heard recently router is needed for for firewall purpose due to attempts on every IP address every day? So is it not needed just for security? If it isn't needed for security purposes, I really have no need for a router then?

Comment: You already have the option of a built in firewall from your Mac's system preferences. My understanding is that with a hardware router you can also configure its own firewall within the routers settings. This may increase your security as you have two firewalls going, but you don't need the router as you already have the option of setting up a firewall within your Mac.

Comment: That is good to hear, thank you! I saw several posts about router being must be or else someone hacks in... but I'm not tech savy so couldn't form a decision myself.